# Adjective for someone who disregards ideas and opinions of some people but not others?

Tags: phrase-requests, adjectives

I am struggling to find an adjective for someone who disregards the ideas and opinions of anyone that they think are not at the same level as them.

For example, a brother or husband who disregards the ideas and opinions of his sister or wife but he will listen to the ideas and opinions of a parent, friend or mentor (who may be male or female).

It is not a problem of class. It is more of a familial attitude, though it could border on patriarchial.

I have looked at the following words but they don't seem to convey what I want to say: arrogant, superior, patronizing, condescending.

I appreciate your input.

Comment: Perhaps add an example sentence where the word or phrase you're looking for might fit - this will help others narrow down the context.

Comment: I hope this helps.   "Why is it that when I give you advice about something, you ignore it? But if Bill says the same thing that I did, then all of a sudden it's the best piece of advice you've ever heard! You are a [adjective] person."

Comment: Please add the example and any other pertinent info to the question itself

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a more general word could be applicable.

> [Biased](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biased): Unfairly prejudiced for or against someone or something.

*Example: He disregarded his wife's argument because of his biased views he got from his father.*

Answer (score 0):

**overweening**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/overweening)

> presumptuously arrogant.
>    an exaggerated opinion of your importance, ability, etc

As in:

> The arrogance of my **overweening** cousin is simply overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it conveys what I want to say. I have responded to @tmgr with an example sentence, which I hope conveys what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of *one* word or phrase that ticks all your boxes. Maybe some combination of the words and phrases below might convey what you want.

---

**Hypocrite** or **hypocritical** might be of some use in highlighting *the inconsistency of the behaviour* in ignoring some people but not others:

> [**hypocrite**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hypocrite#hypocrite_4) *(noun)*
>
> a person who claims to have certain moral principles or beliefs but behaves in a way that shows they are not sincere

User Valrog suggests [**biased**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/464504/230552) above - a perfectly good answer.

In a very similar vein, **bigot** or **bigoted** might work - they are somewhat stronger than **biased**, and suggest *an unreasonably closed mind,* rather than a mere partiality one way or another:

> [**bigoted**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bigoted#bigoted_3)
>   *(adjective)*
>
> someone who is bigoted has opinions that most people think are
>   unreasonable, especially about politics, race, or religion, and
>   refuses to consider other people’s opinions

To get more specific, if it *is* a sex-based discriminination, which you seem to suggest might be the case, the person in question might be called a **chauvinist**. (I think the noun is more commonly used than the adjective, *chauvinistic.*)

> [**chauvinist**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chauvinist) *(noun)*
>
> someone who believes that their own country, race, sex, or group is
>   better than any other; this word is used especially about men and
>   their attitude towards women.

Another idiom that might work for you is:

> [**pick and
>   choose**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+and+choose)
>
> to choose very carefully from a number of possibilities; to be
>   selective.
>
> *You must take what you are given. You cannot pick and choose.*
>
> *Meg is so beautiful. She can pick and choose from a whole range of boyfriends.*

**Selectively deaf** or **selective hearing** also *might* describe one aspect of the situation in your question. This phrase hasn't made it into the dictionaries yet, but I'd think it would be generally understood.

Both the excerpts below try to put *selective deafness* in a scientific context. However, the phrase as usually used is heavily sarcastic, implying that there is no actual deafness at all.

> ### ['Selectively deaf' husbands might have a point](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/8538422/Selectively-deaf-husbands-might-have-a-point.html)
>
> #### "Did you hear me?" It's a question that many an exasperated wife has asked her husband.
>
> *By Stephen Adams, Medical Correspondent, 27 May 2011*
>
> The question is usually delivered in ironic fashion, because how could
>   he not have heard her request to unload the dishwasher? Does the
>   newspaper really rustle that loudly?  But now men have an answer to
>   the charge that they are '**selectively deaf**'.  For scientists at
>   University College London have discovered that people really can "tune
>   out" the sounds around them to concentrate on the matter at hand...

---

> ### [Is ‘selective hearing’ actually a thing?](https://www.health24.com/Medical/Hearing-management/Anatomy-of-hearing/is-selective-hearing-actually-a-thing-20160617)
>
> #### Why can your partner never hear the phone ringing? It could be that their brains are wired to ignore some sounds.
>
> We can all recall times when we were so engrossed in something that we
>   were oblivious to our surroundings.
>
> Regularly recurring sounds also often don’t register, especially if
>   they don’t require any reaction from us. An example is people living
>   next to a railway line who don’t hear the passing trains anymore.
>
> There’s a difference between physically hearing a sound and
>   consciously registering it. To put it simply, you “hear” what you
>   focus on or pay attention to – even if you choose not to react. A case
>   in point is when someone at a cocktail party manages to drown out the
>   peripheral noise to have a conversation with one or two people. 
>   **Selective hearing is not necessarily a case of people pretending not to hear**, it’s actually a way for our brains to filter out extraneous
>   noise so we can concentrate on what’s important at that moment.

(Emphasis in the quotes above is mine.)